# PhoneGap catch 'Enter' pressed event for iPhone and android on anchor tag

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova

I want to know how to catch 'Enter' pressed event using PhoneGap.

I have a form with a anchor tag. How do I catch when user has pressed "Enter" in keyboard. i have write javascrpt

```
<head>
<script  language="javascript">
$("a.submit").click(function ()
{
  if(window.event.keyCode == 13)
   {
     alert(window.event.keyCode);
   }
}
</script></head>
<body>
<a id="submit" href="abc.html" class="abc">
</body>
```

Comment: <a> tag is not a input field or a textarea. You can not get "Enter" event.

Comment: @jyoti Prakash that i know its not input field but i want that on keypad go button it must be redirect to its designation how can i do that using javascript.

Comment: How keypad will open on anchor tag ??